# Making dynamic canvas a background to a div using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, background

I want to make a dynamic background to a specific component in my website using React. I want to make it so this background is a canvas running a react-particle-js simulation. Everything is inside a React Component and being rendered with the `render()` method, as usual. The result should look

[image: something like this]

The code for the component that has the background should look something like this:

```
class ParticleBackgrondComponent extends Component{

render(){
    return (

        <div>
            <Particles/> {//The particle background}

            <h3>
                Some other content
            </h3>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
            </p>

        </div>
    )
}
```

}

I've tried setting the position of said canvas to absolute and manually putting it behind the div that I wanted, but it doesn't work when I resize the window.

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible reproducible example.

Comment: Are you recreating https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-particles-js? Or just using it and trying to figure out how to work with it? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example.

Comment: I've added some code to the question. Also, yes, I'm working with the react-particles-js package @DrewReese

Comment: There is a draft for an [`element()` function](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-4/#element-notation) that would fit your need perfectly, but it has not been implemented anywhere except firefox (with vendor prefix). You might be forced to use a trick such as absolute positioning.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [`CSS element() function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/element).

```css
.dynamic-background {
  background: element(.particle-canvas);
}
```

However, currently (April 2020) it is only supported by firefox using the non-standard `-moz-element()`. If you plan on targeting more browsers in the present I recommend looking for alternative solutions.

Comment: I wish everybody used firefox. It's a nice way of doing it, but for my application, it really needs to be compatible with most browsers. Thank you, though

Comment: @JoaoLuz There is also [CSS Paint API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Painting_API/Guide) that is supported in Chrome and Edge. So you could use a combination of `paint()` and `element()` inside `@supports` (however Safari users will just see a static).

Answer (score 1):

So, I've found a way to do it. Basically I'm trying to resize and reposition the canvas, based on the `getBoundingClientRect` method ([see documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)), every time the window resizes:

```
class ParticleBackgroundComponent extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        //to help us get the boundingClientRect
        this.selector = React.createRef();

        //our state variables that store dimensions an position of the background
        this.state = {
            width: 0,
            height: 0,
            top: 0
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        /*the first event listener to figure out when the page is done loading
        (use this if you have images in the component)*/
        window.addEventListener('load', () => {

            //setting the state to draw the background the first time
            var rect = this.selector.current.getBoundingClientRect();
            this.setState({
                width: rect.width,
                height: rect.height,
                top: rect.top + window.scrollY
            });

            //second event listener for resizing
            window.addEventListener('resize', ()=>{
                //redraw the background every time the page resizes 
                rect = this.selector.current.getBoundingClientRect();
                this.setState({
                    width: rect.width,
                    height: rect.height,
                    top: rect.top + window.scrollY
                })
            });

        });
    }

    //to render the particles
    renderBackground(){
        var width = this.state.width;
        var height = this.state.height;
        var top = this.state.top;

        //using a div to set the position of the background
        return (
            <div style={{position: "absolute", top: t, zIndex: -1}}>
                <Particles width={width} height={height}/>
            </div>
        )
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div ref={this.selector}>

                <h1>
                    Some more content
                </h1>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet...
                </p>

                {this.renderBackground()}

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

What a long answer. I don't think this is the best way to do it (and definitely not the most efficient) as I'm pretty new to using React and even Javascript for that matter. If anyone can improve this answer, by all means, do so

Answer (score 0):

While `element()` remains unsupported you can absolutely position the background element behind the foreground element and dynamically set the width and the height of the canvas based on the size of the foreground:

```js
const TAU = 2 * Math.PI;

class Circle {
  constructor(canvas) {
    this.x = Math.random() * canvas.width;
    this.y = Math.random() * canvas.height;
    this.r = Math.random() * Math.sqrt(canvas.width ** 2 + canvas.height ** 2) / 8;
    this.growth = Math.random() * 4;
    this.decay = Math.max(Math.random() * 0.005, 0.0005);
    this.rgb = [
      Math.random() * 255,
      Math.random() * 255,
      Math.random() * 255,
    ];
    this.alpha = Math.random() * 0.35;
  }
  
  get fillStyle() {
    return `rgba(${this.rgb.join(',')},${this.alpha})`;
  }
  
  render(ctx) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.fillStyle;
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, TAU);
    ctx.fill();
    
    this.r += this.growth;
    this.alpha -= this.decay;
  }
}

function render(ctx, foreground, circles = []) {
  const { width, height } = foreground.getBoundingClientRect();
  ctx.canvas.width = width;
  ctx.canvas.height = height;

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  
  if (circles.length === 0) {
    circles.push(new Circle(ctx.canvas));
  }
  
  if (Math.random() > 0.98) {
    circles.push(new Circle(ctx.canvas));
  }
  
  for (const circle of circles) {
    circle.render(ctx);
  }
  
  window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    render(ctx, foreground, circles.filter(circle => circle.alpha > 0))
  });
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
  const foreground = document.querySelector(".foreground");

  render(canvas.getContext("2d"), foreground);
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.background {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <canvas class="background"></canvas>
  <div class="foreground">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur placerat quam a vulputate tincidunt. Aliquam pretium leo quis justo pretium, in pellentesque augue viverra.</p>
    <p>Quisque lacinia ipsum id purus varius molestie. Integer tincidunt elementum condimentum. Praesent molestie, nunc sed ullamcorper accumsan, augue urna maximus lorem, at venenatis orci tellus vitae leo.</p>
    <p>Pellentesque eget lacus sagittis, sollicitudin mauris eget, hendrerit est. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sapien odio, ullamcorper in erat vitae, mollis vulputate leo.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
```